# only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
    
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\WD\Desktop\choi\data\data\android\build.gradle' line: 34
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\WD\Desktop\choi\data\data\android\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> build file 'C:\Users\WD\Desktop\choi\data\data\android\build.gradle': 34: only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block

@ line 34, column 1.
plugins {
^

1 error

i changed the order that

plugins{ id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'}
this thing but doesnt work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle has a strict restriction on the ordering of some blocks, you should not be confused by this. This is due to the fact that some of the blocks must be read before all the others.

Just chahnge the order of the blocks in your `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: i think this code works but new error
package identifier or launch activity not found.

Comment: That means that you have another errors in your `build.gradle`. Update your question with new errors @최경민